# Replace javascript controlled button with image

Tags: javascript, css

I am using javascript to control a button for a 3d carousel and trying to use an image instead of the button. My HTML looks like:

```
<button id="previous" data-increment="-1" >Previous</button>
  <button id="next" data-increment="1">Next</button>
```

I tried the obvious by adding img tag where "Next" and "Previous" are:

```
<button id="previous" data-increment="-1" ><img src="URL" /></button>
```

That made the images appear, but when clicked they do nothing. I also tried to alter it with CSS and could change the style of the buttons, but the same images would not appear for both buttons. I need separate images for Next and Previous:

```
button {
background-image: url(images/myimage.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
border: none;
}

button span {
display: none;
}
```

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here.

1. There is no span element in your buttons. `button span` style isn't doing anything for you. If you want to hide the text, I suggest using `color: transparent;`.
2. You need to apply a different image for each button, which means you need different selectors.

   button#previous {
       background-image: url('prev.jpg');
   }

   button#next {
       background-image: url('next.jpg');
   }
3. Generally, applying styles to a button won't affect listeners added in js. Something must be wrong in your js if the buttons aren't working anymore. Please post the relevant code if you'd like help with this.

Comment: Cool! Please accept the answer when it allows you to (I know there is a time limit)